# GCP - vulnerabilityReports.get() with Python

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

I am trying to get the vulnerability report for an instance as part of a Python script. For that I am following the documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/rest/v1alpha/projects.locations.instances.vulnerabilityReports/get

My function looks something like this:

```
    def getVulnerability()
        project = "my-project"
        location = "my-zone"
        instance = "my-instance-id"
        service.projects().locations().instances().vulnerabilityReports().get(
        parent='projects/{}/locations/{}/instances/{}'.format(project, location, instance)
        )
```

However, when I run that I get an error saying

> TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "parent"

What exactly can I do to resolve this or how should I change my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation, it seems like the parameter is no longer `parent`. Can you please try it using the v1 version (rather than v1alpha) and passing the parameter `name` instead?

```py
def getVulnerability()
   project = "my-project"
   location = "my-zone"
   instance = "my-instance-id"
   service.projects().locations().instances().vulnerabilityReports().get(
        name='projects/{}/locations/{}/instances/{}'.format(project, location, instance)
    )
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/rest/v1/projects.locations.instances.vulnerabilityReports/get

Comment: Can't believe the answer was right in front of me this whole time! Thank you very much for the help!